# Bytes as hex in python

Tags: python, byte

I want to convert int to 4 bytes of data, but when I'm using to_byte() function, the results is not what I'm expecting. I know it's right value but i want to convert it to hex type.
So for example:

```
length = 13
length.to_bytes(4, byteorder='big')
```

output:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\r'
```

And now how can I quickly convert it to:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x0d'
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because 13 is mapped to "r" on the ASCI table

`length.to_bytes(4,byteorder='big').hex()`
will show it as hex.

If you just want to write `13` in binary to a file:

```py
length = 13
file = open('file.bin', 'bw') # Open file in binary write mode.
file.write(length.to_bytes(4,byteorder='big'))
file.close()
```

Comment: Yeah, I know but I need it to be hex to write it to .png file as chunk.

Comment: You don't write hex into a file. It is only another representation of binary

Comment: The .hex() function will return a string with the binary date represented in hex format.

Comment: @Hubert oh so you just need to write the bytes to a file? That's hugely important information to include in your original post because that's very different than what you were asking about. Just because the representation is showing ASCII escape codes for certain bytes doesn't mean that the bytes aren't correct. Just try writing it to a file and looking at the output in a hex editor - it will be what you expect. Please try basic debugging, like doing that, before posting questions here, especially when you leave out important information, because you're wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Yeah, if you just want to write the integer 13 into a file you don't need to convert it to any specific format.

Comment: Thank you guys for your effort in explaning my problem, next time I will make my posts more clear.